# Dependent dropdowns only working for first row in dynamic content

Tags: java, jquery, spring, model-view-controller

I am dynamically adding/removing rows and dependant dropdowns using Spring MVC. For the first row the dependent dropdown is working but for the next rows it's not working?

This is the view:

```js
var max_fields1 = 7;
var faqs_row1 = 3;

$("#addfaqs1").click(function(e) {
  // var bla = $('#accommodationTypeId').val();
  // alert(+bla);
  e.preventDefault();
  if (faqs_row1 < max_fields1) {
    var addGuestHtml = 
      '<div class="row" id="faqs-row' + faqs_row1 + '">' +
        '<div class="col-sm-3">' +
          '<div class="form-group">' +
            '<span class="small"><b>' + faqs_row1 + '.</b> Guest House Type </span>' +
            '<select type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="accommodationTypeId' + faqs_row1 + '" id="accommodationTypeId' + faqs_row1 + '" class="selectpicker show-tick shadow" placeholder="Select Room Type" title="Type of Room Type..." data-live-search="true" onchange="populateRoomType(this.value)" data-width="100%" >' +
              '<option value="0">select Guest House</option>' +
              '<option th:each="item: ${accommodationTypeId}" th:value="${item.buildingId}" th:text="${item.buildingName}"></option>' +
            '</select>' +
            '<div class="invalid-feedback text-danger Guest House Type"></div>' +
          '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="col-sm-3">' +
          '<div class="form-group">' +
            '<span class="small"> Room Type </span>' +
              '<select type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="roomTypeId' + faqs_row1 + '" id="roomTypeId' + faqs_row1 + '" class="selectpicker show-tick shadow" placeholder="Select Room Type" title="Type of Room Type..." data-live-search="true" data-width="100%" />' +
              '<div class="invalid-feedback text-danger Room Type"></div>' +
            '</div>' +
          '</div>' +
          '<div class="col-sm-3">' +
            '<div class="form-group">' +
              '<span class="small">Number of rooms </span>' +
              '<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="noOfRooms" id="noOfRooms' + faqs_row1 + '" value="" placeholder="Number of Rooms" />' +
              '<div class="invalid-feedback text-danger Number of Rooms"></div>' +
            '</div>' +
          '</div>' +
          '<div class="col-sm-1">' +
            '<div class="form-group">' +
              '<span>&nbsp;</span>' +
              '<button type="button" onclick="$(\'#faqs-row' + faqs_row1 + '\').remove();" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm form-control" title="remove guest" ><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button>' +
              // '<button type="button" onclick="$(\'#faqs-row' + faqs_row1 + '\').remove();" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm form-control removeGuest" title="remove guest" ><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button>'+
            '</div>' +
          '</div>';
        '</div>';
    $("#addGuestDiv1").append(addGuestHtml);
    faqs_row1++;
  }
});
```

Controller:

```java
public String bookingHomePage(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) throws Exception 
{
  model.addAttribute("accommodationTypeId", this.infraRoomViewService.findByInfraRoomActiveFlag());
  return "booking";
}
```

Comment: You cannot use Thymeleaf attribute with js.

Comment: Any other Alternate is there for this problem